# space under footer on large screen resolution

Tags: css-position

I've got a problem with a website I am working on currently. The website displays correctly until tested on a 1280x1024 screen, where an extra chunk of space appears right under the footer. Body is set to `height:auto`and the divs are all set to `position:relative`. Body has all margins removed, this happens only when tested on the larger screen. 
I checked whether jquery hidden divs are causing this, and it definitely isn't it. I tried adding @media rule for the screen res in question, but this works only my Firefox responsive design view tool. I think I checked all I could and I am stuck.

Any ideas what may this be caused by?

Cheers

Comment: Can we have a link or a fiddle demonstrating this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your likely after is a sticky footer example [here](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Basically add a div in your last content section to push the footer down like so.

Place this as last element in `#desc`

```
<div class="push"></div>
```

then add this to your css

```
.push {
  height:110px; //height of your footer
  margin-bottom:-110px;
}
```